# How to fire JS event in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using selenium WebDriver syntax. I know, that in selenium server-based syntax, you can fire an javascript event by doing:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", server.getPort(),
            "*iexplore", "http://www.eviltester.com");
selenium.fireEvent("lteq30", "blur");
```

how do I do the same in an application, created with WebDriver (for example, FirefoxDriver)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately the Selenium WebDriver designers explicitly [decided not to include](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1671) this functionality in Selenium 2.

> It's a deliberate decision to not include this feature in WebDriver,
>   since it's usually a hack to work around synthesized events not
>   behaving properly. We'd rather eliminate this need by providing great
>   support for native events, so we'll continue improving that going
>   forward. A user would never fire a focus event, they would click the
>   form control. That's what your tests should be doing as well.

With that said, you **can** execute any javascript code you want. Thus you should look into *how to fire events with javascript*. Take at look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) for inspiration.

Then you can do something like this:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.ExecuteScript("[your fire event javascript code]");
```

I'm sure you could create a wrapper function to basically accomplish the same thing as `fireEvent`.

Comment: Will simply running the click() event in JS do the job or do I actually need to run the specific function in the code? If it's the latter, that seems like an ugly dependency to introduce into tests.

Comment: I understand their decision, but .sendKeys() should trigger keyDown keyUp change events, or perhaps .sendKeyWithEvents(). Otherwise you can't trigger basic events.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('element').blur()");
```

Comment: why do you have a return statement in this? would it not work without the return?

Comment: The return statement is not needed for functionality. But with the return statement, you also get the response back.