# How to Test Blur - Firefox Selenium driver?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

I'm using selenium `2.24` Firefox Driver to test an input box's **blur** event. Currently, after I `sendKeys` to an input box, I let selenium to click another area which triggers the input box blur.

However, I think it is not a good way, anyone knows a better way to test this?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't remember if this worked for the onblur event but try webElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

Comment: If you are using C#, then you can insert a `tab` char at the end of the string to send to the element: `ele.SendKeys("my string\t")`

Comment: someelement.sendKeys("\t") also works in Java, shortest solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a lil investigation. I found out that fire event is not supported in selenium 2.0. See [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696010/how-to-fire-js-event-in-selenium).
So this piece of code worked for me:

```
 driver.get("http://www.onliner.by/");

        String cssSelctr= "div.b-top-search-box input[id=\"g-search-input\"]";
        WebElement testElement=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelctr));
        testElement.sendKeys("fvsdfs");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelctr+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.blur();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope now this helps you)

Comment: unfortunately using the method will lead to exception:
...........
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:381)
 at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.JavascriptLibrary.callEmbeddedHtmlUtils(JavascriptLibrary.java:82)

Answer (score 7):

Some elements do not have a suitable discriminator for testing purposes (e.g. an id or another CSS selector that you'd like to be bound to in your tests).

Fortunately, the notion of an [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) exisits. So, if the element's blur functionality is what you wish to test, a native javascript way (not reliant upon jQuery or similar) to test this is:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("!!document.activeElement ? document.activeElement.blur() : 0");
```

Answer (score 6):

The selenium WebDriver does not properly trigger events like blur.  You can, however, manually trigger them.  Assuming that you're using jquery:

```
firefoxWebDriver.executeScript("$('#yourID').blur()");
```

Or without jquery:

```
firefoxWebDriver.executeScript("document.querySelector('#yourID').blur()");
```

Comment: This method also works for HtmlUnitDriver, ChromeDriver, SafariDriver, and InternetExplorerDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks eugene.polschikov. I had to change the function to call `triggerHandler` to make it work for me. See the following - just replace "element-id" with the id of  your element.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsexec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("var x = $('" + element-id + "');");
stringBuilder.append("x.triggerHandler('blur');");
jsexec.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "elementId" with relevant element ID. It works fine for me. "driver" is your Selenium driver

> JavascriptExecutor jsexec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
>   jsexec.executeScript("document.getElementById('" + elementId +"').onblur();");